# Format code that is displayed in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, indentation

I'm building a Javascript based UI that generates code based on the UI. I got the code generation working. the code is saved in a string. I tried formatting it, indenting it, but I don't know how anymore. Is there a way to put out the code formatted?

For example if I have this string:

```
"<body><div><h1>Hi</h1></div></body>"
```

being output like this:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>
      Hi
    </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

right now I'm outputing like this:

```
$(".output").text(string);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at code tag in html. Show your string wrapped by code tags

```
<code>your string</code>
```

Or use text area. https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/k1atgn6o/1/

If you are trying to achived the formatted output please have a look at Template literals

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: isn't the code tag only for monospacing, and not for linesplitting or indenting?

Comment: This would work to display it, but the code is saved indented in the string. the display isn't the problem, the indenting is.

Comment: I've read this but this doesn't seem to work. I'll update my question

Comment: @Niqql Can try to help you if you show us what is not working.

Comment: Nevermind this does work! I guess I just implemented it wrong before, my bad! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Niqql Happy to hear that

Answer (score 0):

.text() use for Change the Text of any Tag.

```
$(".output").text(string);
```

.html() is use for Add the String with the Tag.

```
$(".output").html(string);
```

Comment: This will convert all the elements in the string to dom-elements, which is not wanted.

Comment: then you can try $(".output").text("<code>" + string + "</code>");

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display code that is correctly indented and colorized, you can use a library to do that, such as highlighjs.

I'm not sure it does auto indentation, but the algorithm for that isn't that hard: just add newline and enough spaces when opening a new html tag (recursion will make this way easier).

Also, you can use [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify).